# How to create files with content, from a list

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Trying to figure out how to create files(.strm) with specific content using a file list.

Example:

List.txt(content)

```
American Gangster (2007).strm,http://xx.x.xxx.xxx:8000/movie/xxxx/xxx/2017
Mi movie trailer (2019).strm,http://xx.x.xxx.xxx:8000/movie/xxxx/xxx/123
Peter again (2020).strm,http://xx.x.xxx.xxx:8000/movie/xxxx/xxx/5684

etc.
```

I was able to create the .strm files using the below script:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="path/list.txt"
while IFS= read -r  line
do
#       echo "$line"
        touch "$line"
done < "$filename"`
```

but this leaves me with empty files, how can I read and append the content?

Desire output:

Filename: AmericanGangster(2007).strm

Inside the file: http://xx.x.xxx.xxx:8000/movie/xxxx/xxx/2017

Thanks

Comment: What's the filename you want? `'/'` isn't a valid filename character for any OS and `':'` isn't valid on Mac or Windows, so `test1,http://www.123` isn't a valid filename.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the contents of the file to the file names that you created. Try

```
filename=path/list.txt
while IFS= read -r line; do
  if [[ -e $line ]]; then  ##: The -e tests if the file does exists.
    echo "${line##*,}" > "${line%,*}"
  fi
done < "$filename"
```

Since there can't be a filename with a '/' in it the `-e` is not needed.

```
filename=path/list.txt
while IFS= read -r line; do
  echo "${line#*,}" > "${line%,*}"
done < "$filename"
```

It can be done by setting IFS to `IFS=,`

```
while IFS=, read -r file contents; do 
  echo "$contents" > "$file"
done < "$filename"
```

... Or awk.

```
awk -F, '{print $2 > $1}' "$filename"
```

- The `,` must not appear anywhere except where it is now, otherwise all solution will break.

Comment: Thanks for responding, no I would not be create a file with the word test on its name.
this is how the file looks like line by line: separated by ,

moviename,linkofmovielocation

Comment: Please edit the question and put the actual contents of the file, and the desired result, output